# A function to for condition Z**n == a + bi

Tags: python, math

I need to create a function in Python which includes complex numbers.

z**n = a + bi

How can I create this?

Comment: is i the imaginary number?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What is the function supposed to do? What is the expected return value?

Comment: Are you trying to solve for z given a, b and n? Do you want all solutions or just one? Maybe you could give some examples of desired inputs and outputs

Comment: The function needed to prove z**n equals to a + bi. The answer Luka Mesaric gave helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has inbuilt support for complex numbers, and `pow` does exactly what you need.

```
z = 4 + 5j
n = 3
print(pow(z, n))
```

If you have just `a` and `b`, you can get `z` using `z = complex(a, b)`.

Comment: z = complex(a, b) helped. Thanks for the answer.